# Only call Rails Active Record callback on successful model create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I want to add  `after_create :my_function` to one of my models. How can I make sure this method is only called on successful creates or updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use after_save. This callback is called on both create and updates (or, any call to the save method) so long as the callback chain isn't broken before the save completes (validation errors, etc). You can see some examples in the docs:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save

Comment: So I need to call two separate functions, Function A after a model is created, and Function B after the model is updated.

Comment: If you want different behavior for create and update, you can use both the  after_create and after_update callbacks. If you want the same behavior for both, I'd recommend just using one method and using the after_save callback.

Comment: Thanks Pete, but that gets me back to the original question - when I use after_create and after_update, how do I only run these when the model was successfully saved?

Comment: I can't test it now, but using `after_save` and test inside your function if it is an update or not with `updated?`, then call an other function on result.